# Which is correct - "{When / As / Since / Whether} she was 18 years old, she entered the order..."?

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

Choose correct option and explain why?

> ___ she was 18 years old, she entered the order of the Sister of Our
>   Lady of Loreto, in India.
>
> 1. When
> 2. As
> 3. Since
> 4. Whether

Well, All we know that the "Whether" is unrelated but from the book perspective, "When" is correct option. I couldn't understand? why not "As"?

---

**Additional info**:

It was one of the [Konkour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_University_Entrance_Exam) questions.

> Konkour (Persian: کنکور; from the French Concours), is a standardized
>   test used as one of the means to gain admission to higher education in
>   Iran.

[image]
As you see, we don't have extra context for the question (not before and not after.), every question is independent.

Comment: Indeed. 2 and 3 are perfectly good _if the context has already been set_ that we are talking about her leaving school, or entering an order, or starting a career. Because they give a reason, not a time, they would be odd as the first sentence of a piece.

Comment: If you use "as" or "since" you suggest that she entered the order because she was 18 years old.

Comment: I would add one other small, unrelated point. "the order of the Sister of Our Lady of Loreto" is more likely to be "Sisters". Most Christian orders are "Sisters" or "Brothers".

Comment: @ColinFine For **As** maybe but i don't think the option 3 is one of possible correct options because we have learned that after **since** we should use **Present Perfect tense**. but as you can see, the phrase "she entered..." not like this.

Comment: @kokabi: _Since_ can also be used to specify a reason or justification, and in this use it can take a simple past. So number 3 (and indeed number 2) means _Because she was 18 years old ..._

Answer (score 5):

**as** in its *temporal* sense relates to a *coinciding* event, something that happens at the same time as something else:

> He took off his coat as he entered the room.

Temporal **as** is synonymous with **while** (but note, **as he entered** would be better paraphrased as **while he was entering**).

**as** in its *causal* sense refers to a condition that makes something possible, or to an explanation for something.

> She was able to vote, as she was now 18 years old.
>
> They took the car to the repair shop, as it was making a noise.

Causal **as** is synonymous with **since**.

Comment: +1 for the voting sentence – great example! I think _as_ could work for the OP's sentence, too, with a slight modification: _As she was 18 years old, she **could finally** enter the order of the Sister of Our Lady of Loreto._

Answer (score 2):

I think the authors of the quiz book have a simple temporal meaning in mind. I don't think this is about causality, because something else would have prompted her to become a nun beside reaching a certain age (even if there is a precondition that one must be a certain age to join a certain order). Temporal "as" would really be paired with a continuous tense (or a continuous *sense*, like "As she approached adulthood, she began thinking about joining the order"). We don't need to confuse the OP with all the possible ways in which "as" and "since" might be shoehorned into this sentence.

So this is a simple "when", #1.

---

Since the OP specifically asked "why not *as*"—temporal "as" has a meaning of something happening concurrently. Whatever is attached to "as" would most often be describing a period of time, not a single instance. Here, there is a simple sense of having reached 18 years and then entering the order. Simple "when...., she ....".